# Too many XML data bindings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I made a `View` that I want to reuse across many pages. It contains feedback elements for the user such as a `ProgressBar`, `TextView` etc.

Due to high amount of items within, binding all those turns out like this:

```xml
<layout ... >

    <data>
        <variable
            name="screenObserver"
            type="my.namespace.ScreenStateObserver" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... >

        <my.namespace.view.ScreenStateView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:loading="@{screenObserver.isProgressVisible}"
            app:errorText="@{screenObserver.errorTxt}"
            app:buttonText="@{screenObserver.errorBtnTxt}"
            app:errorVisible="@{screenObserver.isTextVisible}"
            app:buttonVisible="@{screenObserver.isButtonVisible}"
            app:onButtonClick="@{() -> screenObserver.onErrorResolve()}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

I find copy/pasting the whole XML block messy and error-prone. Is there any way to make this simpler ?

`ScreenStateObserver` is just a interface that I implement in my `ViewModel` and bind as follows:

```
override fun onCreateView(...): View? {

    val factory = InjectorUtils.provideViewModelFactory()
    viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
        screenObserver = viewmodel
    }
}
```

```
class AtoZViewModel() : ViewModel(), ScreenStateObserver { ... }
```

```
interface ScreenStateObserver {
    val isProgressVisible : MutableLiveData<Boolean>
    val isTextVisible : MutableLiveData<Boolean>
    val isButtonVisible : MutableLiveData<Boolean>

    // [..]
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: can't you just include the view with a `<include>` tag? https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion to reduce code.
First declare a class like this

```
interface ScreenState {

    class Loading : ScreenState

    class Error(val errorMessage: String, val errorButtonText: String) : ScreenState
}
```

and inside you `CustomView` it will be

```
internal class ScreenStateView {

    fun setState(state: ScreenState) {
        if (state is ScreenState.Loading) {
            // show loading
        } else {
            // hide loading
        }

        if (state is ScreenState.Error) {
            //show {state.errorMessage} and {state.errorButtonText}
        } else {
            // hide error
        }
    }
}
```

using in xml

```
    <my.namespace.view.ScreenStateView
        ...
        app:state="@{screenObserver.screenState}"
        ...
        app:onButtonClick="@{() -> screenObserver.onErrorResolve()}" /> // for onButtonClick I think it still better if we keep like this
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<include>` in data binding layouts. Included layout file can have its own data and variables that you can access from the main binding class as well.

You have to create a layout file(such as `layout_state_view.xml` that contains your view and data variables relevant to your view:

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="screenObserver"
            type="my.namespace.ScreenStateObserver" />
    </data>


        <my.namespace.view.ScreenStateView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:loading="@{screenObserver.isProgressVisible}"
            app:errorText="@{screenObserver.errorTxt}"
            app:buttonText="@{screenObserver.errorBtnTxt}"
            app:errorVisible="@{screenObserver.isTextVisible}"
            app:buttonVisible="@{screenObserver.isButtonVisible}"
            app:onButtonClick="@{() -> screenObserver.onErrorResolve()}" />


</layout>
```

Now you can include this in your root layout file:

```
<layout>
       <data>
         ...
       </data>

    <LinearLayout     //Can be any layout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <include 
 layout:="@layout/layout_state_view">

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now when you are using binding class, if you root layout file was R.layout.mainActivity then it would look like this:

```
binding.layoutStateView.setScreenObserver(...)
```

You can also make a variable in root layout and pass that variable to child layout by using `bind` tag as mentioned on documentation but since you are looking to reduce code, it would be unnecessary.

Note: Since you only have a single view, you might be tempted to use `<merge>` tag. Databinding's layout tag does not support `merge` as a direct child.

> Documentation Reference:
>   https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#includes

Answer (score 0):

My solution to reduce code is first define class for ScreenStateView(different properties of ScreenStateView in this class) then use it as much times as you needed